# delete specified element of the list stored at the specified key in php redis

Tags: php, redis

How can I delete a specified element of the list stored at the specified key in php redis?
I know its possible to return an element using

```
$redis->lGet('key', 'index value');
```

But how can I delete  a specific element using its index value or any other way? 
Please help...

Comment: Have you looked at their [`manual`](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis) ?

Comment: Yes. I have used 

 $redis->lRem('key', 'index value');

But its not working

Answer (score 2):

With `$redis->lRem(..)`. For example

```
$redis->lPush('key1', 'A');
$redis->lPush('key1', 'B');
$redis->lPush('key1', 'C'); 
$redis->lPush('key1', 'A'); 
$redis->lPush('key1', 'A'); 

$redis->lRange('key1', 0, -1); /* array('A', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A') */
$redis->lRem('key1', 'A', 2); /* 2 */
```

This will return

```
$redis->lRange('key1', 0, -1); /* array('C', 'B', 'A') */
```

Taken from [manual](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#example-48)